# copy and write excel sheet on the the same time in python

Tags: python, excel

I want to try to copy and write excel sheet on the same time. Is it possible?

sheet0 means i want to copy excel sheet

sheet1 means i want to convert textfile to excel file

sheet2 means i only print some value to excel

```
import glob
import xlwt
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy

openFile = 'D:/workspace/list/*.txt'
rb = xlrd.open_workbook('C:/users/desktop/list.xls')

....
for filename in glob.glob(openFile):
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="latin1")
    wb = copy(rb)
    sheet0 = wb.get_sheet(0)
    sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('INPUT')
    sheet2 = wb.add_sheet('VALUE')
....

    wb.save("newTest.xls")
```

Comment: Did you tried it? Did it give you some exceptions? We need more information.

Comment: i already try it and the output like this               UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)